# Можно ли использовать код проектов из разных решений?

Tags: c#, проектирование, nuget, проекты

...иначе, чем путём публикации/подключения пакетов в NuGet или копирования?
Есть два решения, которые:

1. Пользуются общими библиотеками (допустим, это уйдёт в NuGet, там же как-то приватно можно опубликовать их для локального использования?)
2. Один из проектов частично пользуется моделью другого проекта.

Пока писал вопрос, то подумал, что я мог бы добавить во второй проект необходимые интерфейсы, т.к. всё равно данные планирую через Wcf получать, то можно как бы "расширить" Апи, который планируется использовать, но я планировал передавать далеко не все данные, моделью которых пользуюсь во втором решении...
Может я чего-то очевидного не знаю/не понимаю, или просто неправильно спроектировал (пет-проект, поэтому "старших" товарищей, которые могли бы подсказать, не имею)

Comment: 1) не надо нугетов, просто клонируйте репозиторий с библиотекой на локальный комп и подключайте как проект к основному приложению, никакой магии. 2) все что используется более одного раза - должно выноситься в отдельную сборку, то есть в библиотеку. Иначе сколько раз код будет продублирован, столько раз потом придется вносить одну и ту же доработку в разных мечтах. DRY - "не повторяй себя".

Comment: Ну, это мой код в обоих случаях, он и так у меня локально на компьютере находится. Вопрос в том, что у меня два "основных приложения", каждое из которых по-разному использует один и тот же проект.
Пока всё это находилось в одной каше, проблем не было — ссылки на один и тот же проект в одном репозитории, но потом я решил, что пора всё это дело разделить, и теперь думаю, как быть. Не подключать же мне из второго приложения проект, находящийся в папке первого?

Comment: От этого ничего не меняется. Выносите код в отдельную библиотеку, подключаете проект с ней к основному приложению и готово. К двум, трем, десяти приложениям, без разницы.

Comment: @aepot , спасибо. Действительно, на ровном месте себе проблему придумал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Последовал совету уважаемого **@aepot**, просто подключил искомый проект в два солюшена. Спасибо!

Последовательность действий:

1. Имеем оба решения локально (скачиваем/клонируем).
2. Открываете решение (пусть будет "решение-реципиент"), в котором необходимо использовать код из уже существующего в другом решении проекта (назовём второе решение: "решение-донор").
3. Кликаете правой кнопкой по заголовку решения-реципиента, выбираете пункт "добавить существующий проект" (или аналогичную англоязычную версию этой кнопки), и указываете *.csproj файл искомого проекта из решения-донора.
4. ??? Профит!

В моём случае, я использовал часть модели (вынесена в отдельный проект) в обоих решениях, поэтому в одном решении я эту модель храню, а в другом — подключил из "внешнего" репозитория.
Как будут отображаться изменения модели в обоих репозиториях, пока не знаю, поэтому не проконсультирую. Если будет интересно: пишите коммент — допишу.

P.S. В системе контроля версий в репозитории решения-реципиента не отображается заимствованный проект, т.к. физически этот проект находится вне репозитория. По-крайней мере hg это так происходит (думаю, что в git будет аналогично).
Соответственно все изменения в этот проект нужно фиксировать в репозитории, **в котором его файлы** собственно и находятся. *Наталкивает на мысли о ещё одном разбиении моих решений на ещё более мелкие репозитории/решения.*

Comment: В гит есть submodules, но для проектов одного человека это такой оверхед, что проще все в один репозиторий сложить по разным папкам

Comment: За наводку спасибо. В перспективе планируется, что людей будет >1, поэтому хочется сразу нормально спроектировать, чтобы можно было раздать работу.